How to install Flutter version between 3.4.3 and 4.0.0 with Dart 3.4.3?
I have a Flutter application that requires the following versions for compatibility:
Flutter version: Between 3.4.3 and 4.0.0.
Dart version: 3.4.3.
However, I am unable to find Flutter 3.4.3 or a version between 3.4.3 and 4.0.0 in the official release archive or through the Flutter version command.

Flutter version command: flutter version 3.4.3 but I get an error indicating the version doesn't exist.

Flutter release archive: The Flutter 3.4.x versions are not listed on the official release archive.


How can I install and use a version of Flutter between 3.4.3 and 4.0.0 along with Dart 3.4.3 for my project?
What I need:
Instructions on how to install a Flutter version between 3.4.3 and 4.0.0.
Ensuring the corresponding Dart version is also 3.4.3.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

what you are talking about is the version of dart, not the version of flutter, to help you, please run flutter doctor and update your question with the result of that command

Dart 3.4.4 (what your pubspec is probably wanting) is Flutter 3.22.3.  You can install it and use it for specific projects using Puro (https://puro.dev)

The latest flutter versions is 3.27.1 which uses Dart 3.6.0. You can see on https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive which version of flutter corresponds with which dart version. As you can see there, if you want to use Dart version 3.4.3 you need to use Flutter version 3.22.2
